# GORM - unique constraint seems to be ignored when using mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails, unique-constraint, grails-domain-class, database

Here is the domain class:

```
class User {
    String name
    String email

    static constraints = {
        name()
        email(unique: true)
    }
}
```

The email unique property is being ignored when I call save method, and a duplicated records is created. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution:

```
 static mapping = {
    email index:true, indexAttributes: [unique:true]
 }
```